# How to find nuget package sort by most downloaded using the console?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm using **visual studio 2013**. I want to find nuget package using the powershell script but when I search for a package if I don't type the exact name, I get all the packages with the key words mentionned.

For instance, if I write this line : `Get-Package -Filter moq -First 10 -ListAvailable`, I find the top ten packages with the moq keyword but sort by alphabetical order.

Is there a solution to sort this result with the most downloaded order ?

*I know it is possible to do this operation using the GUI  but I want the command line*

Sorry, for my english, I'm not a native speaker and thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Sort-Object` to order the packages by number of downloads:

```
Get-Package -Filter moq -ListAvailable | Sort-Object -Descending -Property DownloadCount
```

If you also want to see the number of downloads you can also use `Select-Object` to get the number of downloads:

```
Get-Package -Filter moq -ListAvailable | 
    Select-Object ID, Version, Description, DownloadCount  | 
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property DownloadCount
```

Comment: Thanks this answer my question! But is there a way to use the `First` parameter with the commands you send ? (Any links to learn more about it will be fine :) )

Comment: Unfortunately no. Get-Package returns items in unknown order (at least I was not able to find the info about ordering), so you need to get all packages (without using `First` parameter) and order them on client side